# Concatenating XML

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I have three files of xml

```
<step>
<Products>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Cyprus</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Argaka</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Tester</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Coral Bay</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>1</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>2</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Greece</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Region">
            <Name>Corfu</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Aghios Stefanos</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Joanna</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Eleonas</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Kassiopi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 2</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

```
<step>
<Products>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Cyprus</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Argaka</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Jaime</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Greece</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Region">
            <Name>Corfu</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Acharavi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 1</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 2</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Gouvia</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa De Bono</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Kassiopi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 1</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

```
<step>
<Products>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Cyprus</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Aghia Marina</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Aghia Marina</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Coral Bay</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Ascos Coral Villas</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Coral Villa</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Lella Villas</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Greece</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Region">
            <Name>Corfu</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Acharavi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Angelos</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Eleonas</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Aghios Stefanos</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Joanna</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Eleonas</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Kassiopi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Imerolia</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Test Property</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Each file has the same products (by ./name) but with differing sub products (by ./name) and I need to concatenate them into one tree with one product per product/name, containing all sub products on the same rules so that I can output one structure.

I have an xslt method found, that will create a node set as below

```
    <xsl:variable name="step-output">
    <xsl:for-each select="/index/file">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="step-products" select="exsl:node-set($step-output)//Products" />
```

But this, when I create other templates will create three products by product/name, i.e. cyprus will turn up three times.

Does anyone know how to do what I'm after?? My result needs to be as follows

```
<step>
<Products>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Cyprus</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Aghia Marina</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Aghia Marina</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Argaka</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Jaime</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Villa Tester</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
        <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
            <Name>Coral Bay</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Ascos Coral Villas</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Coral Villa</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>Lella Villas</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>1</Name>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                <Name>2</Name>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
    <Product UserTypeID="Country">
        <Name>Greece</Name>
        <Product UserTypeID="Region">
            <Name>Corfu</Name>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Acharavi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Angelos</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Eleonas</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 1</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 2</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Aghios Stefanos</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Joanna</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Eleonas</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Gouvia</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa De Bono</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
            <Product UserTypeID="Resort">
                <Name>Kassiopi</Name>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa Imerolia</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Test Property</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 1</Name>
                </Product>
                <Product UserTypeID="Property">
                    <Name>Villa 2</Name>
                </Product>
            </Product>
        </Product>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: @Designer, you want XSLT code or .NET .. ? Even with C#/VB code you can achieve what you wish to ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <step>
      <Products>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="document(index/file)/step/Products/Product" group-by="Name">
          <Product UserTypeID="{@UserTypeID}">
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Name>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Product" group-by="Name">
              <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
              <Product UserTypeID="{@UserTypeID}">
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Name>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/Product">
                  <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </Product>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </Product>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </Products>
    </step>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need to run it against an index XML document with the structure

```
<index>
  <file>test2010020803.xml</file>
  <file>test2010020804.xml</file>
  <file>test2010020805.xml</file>
</index>
```

that lists the other files you want to process.

XSLT 2.0 stylesheets can be executed with [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) which comes in a .NET and a Java version so it runs everywhere where either at least Java 1.5 or .NET 2.0 is available or can be installed. Other options are [AltovaXML tools](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) (Windows only) and [Gestalt](http://gestalt.sourceforge.net/).

If you are tied to XSLT 1.0 then you can do it as follows, as long as you have exsl:node-set or similar support:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="step/Products/Product" use="Name"/>
  <xsl:key name="k2" match="step/Products/Product/Product" use="concat(../Name, '|', Name)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="rtf">
      <xsl:copy-of select="document(index/file)/*"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <step>
      <Products>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rtf)/step/Products/Product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', Name)[1])]">
          <Product UserTypeID="{@UserTypeID}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', Name)/Product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k2', concat(../Name, '|', Name))[1])]">
              <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
              <Product UserTypeID="{@UserTypeID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('k2', concat(../Name, '|', Name))/Product">
                  <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </Product>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Product>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Products>
    </step>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The keys would look like this:

```
  <xsl:key name="k1" match="step/Products/Product" use="Name"/>

  <xsl:key name="k2" match="step/Products/Product/Product" use="concat(../Name, '|', Name)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k3" match="step/Products/Product/Product/Product"
                     use="concat(../../Name, '|', ../Name, '|', Name)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k4" 
           match="step/Products/Product/Product/Product/Product"
           use="concat(../../../Name, '|', ../../Name, '|', ../Name, '|', Name)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k5" 
           match="step/Products/Product/Product/Product/Product/Product"
           use="concat(../../../../Name, '|', ../../../Name, '|', ../../Name, '|', ../Name, '|', Name)"/>

  <xsl:key name="k6" 
           match="step/Products/Product/Product/Product/Product/Product/Product"
           use="concat(../../../../../Name, '|', ../../../../Name, '|', ../../../Name, '|', ../../Name, '|', ../Name, '|', Name)"/>
```

That is all typed directly here in the forum editor so could have bugs.

Comment: +1. Regarding the use of the `document()` function: The spec states that if the argument is a node-set, it is converted to `string` beforehand, which means that the string value of all nodes after the first one is lost. What am I missing?

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document states: 
"When the document function has exactly one argument and the argument is a node-set, then the result is the union, for each node in the argument node-set, of the result of calling the document function with the first argument being the string-value of the node, and the second argument being a node-set with the node as its only member."
So the result of doing document(index/file) where index/file is a node-set of three nodes is the union of loading each of those three files.

Comment: In your XSLT 1.0 code, exsl:node-set is useless. You may use directly document() in the for-each:
<xsl:for-each select="document(index/file)/step/Products/Product[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', Name)[1])]">

Comment: Erlock, you are wrong. Muenchian grouping relies on keys and keys work per input tree only so the solution first needs to create a result tree fragment where all input nodes from different input trees are copied to one tree (fragment), then exsl:node-set is needed to convert the result tree fragment into a node-set and then you can use the key to group all those nodes in one tree. If I don't build a result tree fragment first I can't group the nodes with Muenchian grouping. And once I have a result tree fragment I also need exsl:node-set to process those nodes with for-each.

Comment: Looking at the XLST 1.0 template idea above, would it be possible for this to be recursive to up to 6 levels deep in the initlai structure sample provided?

Comment: With XSLT 2.0 you could rather easily write a recursive function that should work for any level of nesting (as long as the recursion is not causing a stack overflow).

With XSLT 1.0 if you want to group six levels you need to define six keys and I am not sure it is then possible to write a recursive template doing the grouping for those six levels as each time you need a different expression for the key value. It might however be possible to write an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that generates a second stylesheet with the code for grouping a certain number of levels.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've written 6 named templates that would use the keys you describe, and from testing with two (using the provided keys) I can say it works for some levels then breaks a little. Looking at the keys above, and their implementation in the templates, would you know what key values and expressions to write for the 6 levels? If so, could you post them?? I'm really new to the syntax and struggle a little to understand what to write.

Comment: I will edit my answer as I am not sure how to properly format code samples in a comment.

Comment: Thanks very much for that, works a treat. Thinking on, if the xml had attributes with unique id's per product node i.e. id="" and parentid="" would it make the above a lot simpler?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the text to create your files will work, but may be hard to maintain.

The easiest way would be to parse the XML of all 3 files into object form. Programmatically add the objects under a single parent node then regenerate a new XML file.

**Does your environment make this an acceptable solution?**

Comment: @Jon, you mean .NET or something .. ?
as per his question and tags mentioned he wants to do it using XSLT ..

Comment: I presumed that there was some server side code involved. .Net, Python, PHP etc. However, if this is not the case then my solution would not work.